# How to search through multiple items in Ionic 4?

Tags: ionic4

I have a list of cards that displays multiple Tasks.

html

```
<ion-toolbar>
  <ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" (ionChange)="setFilteredItems()" showCancelButton="focus"></ion-searchbar>
</ion-toolbar>

<ion-card *ngFor="let data of list let i = index">
  <ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-title  class = "linkCenter">{{data.Task}}</ion-card-title>
  </ion-card-header>

  <ion-card-content>
    <p>Status: <span style="color:#222428;" >{{data.StatusName}}</span></p>
    <p>Date: <span style="color:#222428;" >{{data.Date}}</span></p>
    <p>Auditors: <span style="color:#222428;" ><br><b>{{data.Auditors}}</b></span></p>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

I presently have search bar that searches through the `data.Task` with the code below

.ts

```
setFilteredItems() {
  this.list = this.filterItems(this.searchTerm);
}

filterItems(searchTerm: { toLowerCase: () => void; }) {
  return this.searchable.filter((item: { Task: { toLowerCase: () => { indexOf: (arg0: any) => number; }; }; }) => {
    return item.Task.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1;
  });
}
```

What i would like to have is the ability the also  search through

`data.StatusName`, `data.Date`, `data.Auditors`, `data.Task` at the same time.

Is this possible as all post and tutorials seem to only go through searching one item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's focus on the search algorithm part.

My approach would be to:

> 1. **Cast all `searchables` to strings**
> 2. **Remove empty space or regular characters**
> 3. **Concatenate all `searchables` to form 1 long string to represent that item for searching "hayStack"**
> 4. **Change case of needle and hayStack to lowercase**
> 5. **Search for needle in hayStack**

We can then search through your `searchables` with the following.

```
setFilteredItems() {
  this.list = this.filterItems(this.searchTerm);
}

filterItems(needle: string) {
  return this.searchable.filter(item => {
    // assuming all these data are string type
    const hayStack: string = (item.Task + item.StatusName + item.Date + item.Auditors).split(' ').join('').toLowerCase();

    needle = needle.split(' ').join('').toLowerCase();

    return hayStack.includes(needle);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked great.  I am sure your answer will help others stuck on this same issue.